# How can I modify the image with text in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want to draw a canvas graphic like this in an image with dynamic texts in top and bottom: http://www.circlesagility.com/images/Agility%20Logo.gif

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Image to use:</p>
  <img id="scream" width="220" height="220" style="border-radius: 50%;" src="//www.circlesagility.com/images/Agility%20Logo.gif" alt="The Scream">

  <p>Canvas:</p>
  <!--<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">-->
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="320" style="border-radius: 50%;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag. </canvas>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("scream");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      ctx.font = "24px Calibri";
      ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
      ctx.fillText("My Text", 100, 100);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then what is not happening ?

Comment: I don't how to rotate 'My Text' as like the text available in the image. I want to add the 'My Text' in top an bottom of the image